Перенос строк с датами
При переносе строк с датами из листа в лист google таблицы кодом google apps script  через массив "ломается" дата
например было 24.04.20024 19:00, попало в массив, массив вставлен в другой лист и там 24.04.20024 00:00 Кто-то может подсказать причину?

Добро пожаловать на сайт, 777 777! Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой, как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Хм, а разве понятие "дата" включает в себя время? Похоже, у них там именно что дата отдельно, время отдельно.

эхххх, дожить бы до 24.04.20024...

Закрыть эту дичь без примера

сохраните как текст при копировании с листа, а на вставке - поменяйте обратно на дату.
